# VB.NET Try/Catch Block Problem - Why Is Exception not thrown

Tags: vb.net, exception, visual-studio-2017, call, comexception

Hi there I have a situation where my Try/Catch block is not behaving as expected.  In this situation a ComException is generated by a call to an Excel function.  the code is within the Try/Catch block and the exception is caught, however instead of 'bubbling' up throught the call stack as expected, to be dealt with by the calling procedure the code halts.  The code is listed below along with the relevant content from the call stack.

```
    Public Overrides Sub CleanDataSet()
        Const procName As String = "CleanDataSet"


        Try
            _previousState = ""
            _previousPlant = ""

            _firstSourceDataRow = 5
            _currentWorkSheet = _mySourceWorkSheet
            _currentRegion = _currentWorkSheet.UsedRange

            _lastSourceDataRow = _currentRegion.Rows.Count + _firstSourceDataRow - 2

            _myWorkbook = _myXLApp.ActiveWorkbook

            'Add a new worksheet to the workbook and call it AlarmAnalysis
            _currentWorkSheet = _myWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
            _mySheetName = "AlarmAnalysis" & _nextKpiSheetNo
            _currentWorkSheet.Name = _mySheetName

            'Now copy the source data into the RTUAvailability worksheet
            _currentWorkSheet = _mySourceWorkSheet
            Dim regionToCopy As String
            regionToCopy = _currentRegion.Address.ToString
            _currentWorkSheet.Range(regionToCopy).Copy()

            _currentWorkSheet = _myWorkbook.Worksheets(_mySheetName)
            _currentWorkSheet.Paste()

            'Insert an additional title row
            _currentWorkSheet.Rows(3).Resize(1).Insert()

            _logger.SendLog(_typeName & "." & procName & " - Deleting unrequired columns from the KPI data.", NLog.LogLevel.Trace)

            'Now delete the unrequired columns
            DeleteColumns(_currentWorkSheet, _currentRegion, _timeField & ", ALARM NAME, STATUS, SUBSTATION NAME, COMMS ROUTE, KPI ALARM, KPI STATUS", _titleRow)

            'Build the report titles
            _currentWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
            _currentWorkSheet.Range(_timeCol & _firstSourceDataRow).Select()
            _currentRegion = _currentWorkSheet.Range(_timeCol & _titleRow).CurrentRegion

            _firstRow = _currentRegion.Row + 1
            _lastRow = _currentRegion.Rows.Count + _firstRow - 2

            _currentWorkSheet.Range(_eventTypeCol & _firstRow - 1).Value = "EVENT TYPE"
            _currentWorkSheet.Range(_eventTypeCol & _firstRow - 1).AddComment("Widow" & vbCrLf & _
                                                                    "Orphan" & vbCrLf & _
                                                                    "Paired" & vbCrLf & _
                                                                    "Derived")


            _currentWorkSheet.Range(_durationCol & _firstRow - 1).Value = _totalColName
            _currentWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit()

            _currentWorkSheet.Range(_currentWorkSheet.Cells(_firstRow - 1, 1), _currentWorkSheet.Cells(_firstRow - 1, GetColNo(_currentWorkSheet, _firstRow - 1, _totalColName))).Font.Bold = True

            'Now sort the data according to the unique key
            _currentWorkSheet.Range(_timeCol & _firstRow - 1 & ":" & "D" & _lastRow).Select()
            _currentWorkSheet.Range("C5").Sort(Key1:=_currentWorkSheet.Range("C5"), _
                Order1:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Key2:=_currentWorkSheet.Range("A5"), _
                Order2:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Header:=Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _
                MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns)

            'Set some variables for manipulating the data
            _eventTimeColNo = GetColNo(_currentWorkSheet, _firstRow - 1, _timeField)
            _eventTypeColNo = GetColNo(_currentWorkSheet, _firstRow - 1, "EVENT TYPE")
            _plantColNo = GetColNo(_currentWorkSheet, _firstRow - 1, "SUBSTATION NAME")
            _commsRouteNo = GetColNo(_currentWorkSheet, _firstRow - 1, "COMMS ROUTE")
            _originalStatusColNo = GetColNo(_currentWorkSheet, _firstRow - 1, "STATUS")
            _statusColNo = GetColNo(_currentWorkSheet, _firstRow - 1, "KPI STATUS")
            _durationColNo = GetColNo(_currentWorkSheet, _firstRow - 1, _totalColName)

            'Code to iterate through the the rows of data and pair events
            Iterate()

            'Set the variable content in the sheet
            GenerateVariablesSheet(_myWorkbook, _nextKpiSheetNo, _numTimeIntervals)

            'Generate the Widow and Orphans Page
            GenerateWidowsAndOrphansSheet()

            'Now build the pivot tables
            _currentWorkSheet.Activate()

            'If we have valid data to process
            If _currentWorkSheet.Range(_timeCol & _firstRow).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.ValidData = True
                BuildTables(_myWorkbook, _currentWorkSheet, _firstRow - 1, _lastRow, 1, _durationColNo, _durationColNo + 2, "SUBSTATION NAME", _totalColName, _totalColName)
            Else
                Me.ValidData = False
                'Enter the 'No Valid Data' banner in the report'
                Dim banRng As Excel.Range
                banRng = _currentWorkSheet.Range(_timeCol & _firstRow)
                MarkWithBanner(_currentWorkSheet, "NO VALID DATA - View the Widows and Orphans Worksheet", banRng, 24, Color.Red)
                _logger.SendLog(_typeName & "." & procName & " - No valid data to process", NLog.LogLevel.Trace)
            End If

            _currentWorkSheet.Calculate()
            _currentWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw **'CODE HALTS HERE INSTEAD OF EXCEPTION BEING THROWN'**
        Finally

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Here is the Exception generated:

```
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall 
(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object  
Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[]  ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
at Accipiter.PSALERTS2018.Common.NCPCommsAnalysisReport.BuildTables(Workbook 
wBook, Worksheet wSheet, Int64 titleRow, Int64 lastRow, Int64 dataStartCol, 
Int64 dataEndcol, Int64 ptColPos, String plantID, String pivotField, String 
totalColName) 
in C:\Users\TE602510\Documents\_VSSWorkArea\PSALERTS 2018\PSALERTS 
Client\Common\KPIReporting.vb:line 3758
```

Here is the call stack:

```
Common.dll!Accipiter.PSALERTS2018.Common.NCPCommsAnalysisReport.CleanDataSet() Line 4078    Basic
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.InvokeMethod(Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Method TargetProcedure, object[] Arguments, 
    bool[] CopyBack, System.Reflection.BindingFlags Flags)  Unknown
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.CallMethod(Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container BaseReference, string MethodName, 
    object[] Arguments, string[] ArgumentNames, System.Type[] TypeArguments, bool[] CopyBack, System.Reflection.BindingFlags InvocationFlags, bool ReportErrors, 
    ref Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.OverloadResolution.ResolutionFailure Failure)    Unknown
Query.exe!QueryMain.BuildReport(Object dataArray) Line 6069 Basic
Query.exe!QueryMain.uxBWFetch_DoWork(Object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e) Line 809   Basic
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e) Unknown
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(object argument)    Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage msg, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink replySink)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(object o)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() Unknown
```

Comment: @Epistaxis it doesn't look to me like either of those are responsive to the issue raised.

Comment: Are you running in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, runnng in the debugger.